# What are the various debugging strategies of mapreduce code (in java) when we don't get the desired output

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

Being new to mapreduce programming, I am making mistakes while building the sample mapreduce code. I am running my mapreduce programs on the image given by Cloudera (the training school provided).

To debug, I am putting System.out.println statements in the mapper and reducer classes. They help to some extent. But it is not as easy as to run the mapper or reducer program in a debug mode.

Can someone share better ways/strategies to debug the mapreduce code?

Thanks much
nath

Comment: Your question is too generic. In order for us to help, you need to describe what specific issues you have, what you have already tried. I assume you debug with a local job runner (everything within the same jvm). This allows you to set break-points and watch variables in your IDE.  System.out.println is usually bad idea, use slf4j logging instead.

Comment: Got it. Sorry about posting a generic question. May I know why you didn't recommend log4j?

Comment: Because it is a standard logging framework across hadoop. But it does not limit you from using log4j. You can just use log4j bridge and specify you config as usual in log4j.properties

Answer (score 0):

You can run your mapreduce application in 'local' mode. When it runs in local mode it is run as a single program where map function runs first followed by reduce mode. In this mode, eclipse can be attached to the running program and can be debugged as any java program would be debugged. Lots of functional issues can be taken care of in this way. However, if there are logical issues because of distributed processing that might not be caught here. You can go through this

https://acadgild.com/blog/running-mapreduce-in-local-mode-2/

There is too much information on running in local mode on Google. You can browse that too.